# SQL Multiple join on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling to write an query to join tables in oder to get required results
Basically I have 4 tables

1)

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020 |
| 123 | 2021 |
| 456 | 2022 |
| 456 | 2021 |

2)

| id | fulldate | id2 | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 102021 | xyz | 2020 |
| 123 | 102020 | xyz | 2021 |
| 456 | 102021 | abc | 2021 |
| 456 | 102022 | abc | 2022 |

3)

| id3 | fulldate | id2 | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| w12 | 102021 | xyz | 2020 |
| w12 | 102020 | xyz | 2021 |
| a12 | 102021 | abc | 2021 |
| a12 | 102022 | abc | 2022 |

4)

| id4 | fulldate | id3 | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | 102021 | w12 | 2020 |
| 1990 | 102020 | w12 | 2021 |
| 2060 | 102021 | a12 | 2021 |
| 2060 | 102022 | a12 | 2022 |

I would like to get ID and ID4 as result for date 2021
Thus I would like to get:

| ID | ID4 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1990 |
| 456 | 2060 |

My query :

```
Select a.ID, d.ID4
from table1 as a
left join table2 as b on a.id = b.id and a.date = b.year
inner join table3 as c on b.id2 = c.id2  and b.fulldate = c.fulldate
inner join table4 as d on c.id3 = d.id3 and c.fulldate = d.fulldate
where b.year = '2021'
```

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result since you have that b.year condition in the WHERE clause. Move it to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result. (Or write INNER JOIN if you want an INNER JOIN...)

Comment: Your query gives your output ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WPBVf_w-)). I'm voting to close down this post.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` but that shouldn't have impacted your result. The code you provided matches the desired output, so double check your database table structure and query to ensure it matches what you provided us.

**SQL**:

```
SELECT 
  a.ID, 
  d.ID4 
FROM 
  table1 a 
  INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id 
  AND a.date = b.year 
  INNER JOIN table3 c ON b.id2 = c.id2 
  AND b.fulldate = c.fulldate 
  INNER JOIN table4 d ON c.id3 = d.id3 
  AND c.fulldate = d.fulldate 
WHERE 
  b.year = '2021'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/98cd2/9/0)**:

```
|  ID |  ID4 |
|-----|------|
| 123 | 1990 |
| 456 | 2060 |
```